# SQLiteException when creating database - SQLiteException near "android"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a service (listed below) which is trying to create database tables.  The am getting an exception I don't understand when the sql within onCreate() in PlayerTable is executed.  All the code is listed below.  Basically, the service starts up, gets an SQLiteDatabase object, which in turn is calling onCreate() on ClueBuddyOpenHelper which then calls onCreate() in PlayerTable.  The exception occurs when the sql executes.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[NewGameService]
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "android": syntax error
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeSql(Native Method)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:90)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1899)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1839)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at ws.hamacher.cluebuddy.db.PlayerTable.onCreate(PlayerTable.java:32)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at ws.hamacher.cluebuddy.db.ClueBuddyOpenHelper.onCreate(ClueBuddyOpenHelper.java:30)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:165)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at ws.hamacher.cluebuddy.service.NewGameService.onHandleIntent(NewGameService.java:18)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 00:47:43.043: E/AndroidRuntime(4347):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Code:

```
public class ClueBuddyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static ClueBuddyOpenHelper instance = null;

    private ClueBuddyOpenHelper(final Context context) {
        super(context, context.getString(R.string.db_name), null, R.string.db_version);
    }

    public static ClueBuddyOpenHelper getInstance(Context context) {
         if (instance == null) {
             instance = new ClueBuddyOpenHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
         }
         return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        PlayerTable.onCreate(db);
        MoveTable.onCreate(db);
        TurnTable.onCreate(db);
        PersonTable.onCreate(db);
        WeaponTable.onCreate(db);
        RoomTable.onCreate(db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


public class PlayerTable {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "player";

    public static class PlayerColumns {
        public static final String PLAYER_ID = "player_id";
        public static final String TOKEN = "token";
        public static final String NUMBER_OF_CARDS = "number_of_cards";
        public static final String USER_IS_PLAYER = "user_is_player";
        public static final String ACTIVE = "active";
    }

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        sb.append("CREATE TABLE ");
        sb.append(PlayerTable.TABLE_NAME);
        sb.append(" (");
        sb.append(PlayerColumns.PLAYER_ID);
        sb.append(" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ");
        sb.append(PlayerColumns.TOKEN);
        sb.append(" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, ");
        sb.append(PlayerColumns.NUMBER_OF_CARDS);
        sb.append(" INTEGER NOT NULL, ");
        sb.append(PlayerColumns.USER_IS_PLAYER);
        sb.append(" TEXT, ");
        sb.append(PlayerColumns.ACTIVE);
        sb.append(" TEXT NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL(db.toString());
    }

}


public class NewGameService extends IntentService {

    public NewGameService() {
        super("NewGameService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = ClueBuddyOpenHelper.getInstance(this).getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM player;");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM turn;");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM move;");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM person;");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM weapon;");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM room;");


        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(BroadcastReceivers.NEW_GAME_BROADCAST_RECEIVER.getName());
        //broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: `db.execSQL(db.toString());` last line in onCreate(): is it a typo? it should be `db.execSQL(sb.toString());`! in this case, use better variable names.

Comment: Ideally all database operations must one in one class which extends the SQLiteOnlineHelper..Why do you need a seperate class to create each table inside the database..

Comment: I don't know if this a problem. I'm just learning `SQLite` now, but I think the `database version` should be an integer. So ` R.string.db_version` is possibly wrong. Try parsing it to an `Integer` before passing it to the `constructor` of the super class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by guido, you need to change

```
db.execSQL(db.toString());
```

to:

```
db.execSQL(sb.toString());
```

It is sending the string interpretation of your db object as your SQL statement.